# How to adjust for double counting data to account for multiple perspectives in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, data-preprocessing

I am trying to measure if referees are biased in favor of players from the same geographic region (as themselves) in a sport. I want to see if players from the referee's region are more likely to win. For each match, I have the region of the winner, the region of the loser, the region of the ref, the seed of the winner, and the seed of the loser. Ideally, I would like to use logistic regression to adjust for the player skill level using their seed as a proxy.

My data looks something like this:

```r
data = {
winner_region:["A","B","A","D","B"],
loser_region:["B","A","A","C","D"],
ref_region:["D","B","A","C","D"],
winner_seed:[3,23,5,45,65],
loser_seed:[2,53,45,22,4]
}
```

I think that I should use logistic regression on the outcome of the match (win/loss) as 1 or 0. However, I am confused as to how to implement this because win/loss depends on the perspective that you are looking at (the winner wins from their perspective, the loser loses from their perspective)

One approach that I have tried that I think works is stratifying by region and always using the stratified region as the perspective to look at the match from. However, this doesn't give me the "overall" amount of bias present. It just tells me if there is bias present in a given region.

Another idea I have is counting each match twice in my dataset, once from the loser's perspective, and once from the winner's perspective. However, I don't know if this messes up the independence needed for the logistic regression.

How do you recommend that I proceed?